# When inserting strings into linked list, newline occurs, and when fixed causes anomalous behavior?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, c-strings

I am fairly new with linked lists in C and I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track but I've been stuck on this because I have no idea what caused this output. This causes problems because I can't match strings when searching for a node because of the odd behavior of the string format.

I have tried doing `node->title[strcspn(node->title, "\n")] = 0;` but when I use this in the insert method it doesn't do what I want it to do. For instance, we have `Title: [HARDWARE\n]` and call (strcspn) it results in

`[Title: [HARDWARE` instead of `Title: [HARDWARE]`

P.S. I'm only using the brackets to explain the extra extraneous characters in the string so I can compare them using strcmp().

Does anyone know how this could be fixed?

```
Enter title:
HARDWARE
TITLE to search for: [HARDWARE]
Current: []
]urrent: [ELECTRONICS
]urrent: [OUTSIDE GARDEN
]urrent: [INDOOR GARDEN
]urrent: [MILLWORK
]urrent: [LUMBER
]urrent: [APPLIANCES
]urrent: [HARDWARE
...
```

This is the output when printing the curr->title after using either of those lines above.
The only other thing I did was in my main was list a menu below the print list for other functionality but this is the logic related to filling the nodes in the linked list.

Comment: Try `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"` in the `strcspn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid.

For example the function `insertSortedList` (as the function `search`) produces several memory leaks and moreover has undefined behavior.

These memory allocations

```
node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
curr = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
```

do not make a sense. The allocated memory is not used and will be lost.

The node `head` in general can be equal to `NULL`. So accessing for example the data member `next` for a null pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Apart from this the pointer to the head node is not changed within the function because it is passed to the function by reference.

I will show how the function can be written. Try to update other your functions yourself.

```
int insertSortedList( node **head, 
                           const char *title, 
                           const char *category, 
                           double time) 
{
    node *node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        strcpy( node->title, title );
        node->title[ strcspn( node->title, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        strcpy( node->category, category );
        node->category[ strcspn( node->category, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        node->time = time;

        while ( *head != NULL && !( strcmp( node->title, ( *head )->title ) < 0 ) ) 
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }

        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called at least like

```
insertSortedList(&head, title, category, time);
                 ^^^^^
```

If you are using a system that appends string read from a file with two symbols `'\r'` and `'\n'`then you can use the following call of `strcspn`

```
node->title[ strcspn( node->title, "\r\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Comment: @Patrick You need to add to the while loop one more condition.

Comment: @Patrick You should either insert new nodes by the order or in the specified position.